# Blazor custom validation in child component

Tags: .net, validation, blazor, blazor-server-side, c#-3.0

I have this component that goes into a form like

```
    <NumberWithNAAndAmberRanges2 @bind-BindNumber="LocVM.ChartDayStartMinute" 
    NaName="Not Applicable"  NaAllowed="true" 
    AmberRange_Min="10" AmberRange_Max="45" 
    RedRange_Max="59" RedRange_Min="0" />
```

The display is pretty simple it has a bound number input which returns -1 if the n/a box is checked
Then a red (absolute) range that inputs must be inside
And an amber (or normal) range that is expected but if the input is outside of amber but inside red (eg 50 in example above) a check box is displayed to confirm the unusual value.

I have it working and displaying the confirm box for values that need confirming but I need to write a validator that stops the user from proceeding until either within amber or having ticked the box.

So I'm trying to make a validator that is part of the component rather than the validation on the parent model but feeds back to the parent form stopping valid submit.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <InputNumber id="tbNumber" class="form-control"  Value="@DisplayNumber" ValueExpression="() => DisplayNumber"   @oninput="OnValueChanged"/>
        </td>
@if (NaAllowed){ 
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
                        <InputCheckbox  id="cb" Value="@vNA" ValueExpression="() => vNA"  @oninput="OnCheckedChanged"  />
         </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>@NaName</td>
 }
    </tr>
</table> 


@if (AmberRange_Outside){    
 <div>
     <strong>
         @DisplayNumber is out side of expected range of @AmberRange_Min to @AmberRange_Max please confirm below
     </strong>
  </div>
 <div>
            <InputCheckbox  id="cbOutsideAmber" Value="@AmberRange_ConfrimChk" ValueExpression="() => AmberRange_ConfrimChk"    /> Confrim unusual value
 </div>

}else{
 <div>
     Within amber
 </div>
}
@if (RedRange_Outside){    
 <div>
     <strong>
         @DisplayNumber is out side of acceptible range of @RedRange_Min to @RedRange_Max 
     </strong>
  </div> 
}else{
 <div>
     Within red
 </div>
}

@code {
    private Boolean initalSet  = false;
    private Boolean vNA;
    private Boolean RedRange_Outside = false;
    private Boolean AmberRange_Outside = false;
    private Boolean AmberRange_ConfrimChk = false;
    private int? _BindNumber;
    
    [Parameter]
    public int? RedRange_Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int? RedRange_Min { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int? AmberRange_Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int? AmberRange_Min { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public String NaName { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Boolean Required { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Boolean NaAllowed { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int?> BindNumberChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int? BindNumber {
        get { return _BindNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_BindNumber != value || !initalSet )
            {        
                _BindNumber = value;
                if (_BindNumber == null)
                {
                    vNA = false;
                    DisplayNumber = null;
                }
                else if (_BindNumber == -1)
                {
                    vNA = true;
                    DisplayNumber = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    vNA = false;
                    DisplayNumber = _BindNumber;
                }
                if (initalSet)
                {
                    AmberRange_ConfrimChk = false;
                    BindNumberChanged.InvokeAsync(_BindNumber);  
                }
                else { initalSet = true;
                    AmberRange_ConfrimChk = true;}
            }
            
            AmberRange_Outside = AmberOutOfRange(_BindNumber);
            RedRange_Outside = RedOutOfRange(_BindNumber);

        }
    }
    


     protected Boolean RedOutOfRange(int? newNumber)
    {
        if (newNumber != null && (newNumber != -1 || !NaAllowed))
        {
            if ( RedRange_Min != null )
            {
                if (RedRange_Min > newNumber )
                {return true;}
            }
            if ( RedRange_Max != null )
            {
                if (RedRange_Max < newNumber )
                {return true;}
            }
        }
        return false;
    }  
    protected Boolean AmberOutOfRange(int? newNumber)
    {
        if (newNumber != null && newNumber != -1 && !RedOutOfRange(newNumber))
        {
            if (  AmberRange_Min != null )
            {
                if (AmberRange_Min > newNumber )
                {return true;}
            }
            if ( AmberRange_Max != null )
            {
                if (AmberRange_Max < newNumber )
                {return true;}
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int? DisplayNumber { get; set; }

    protected async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string stVal = e.Value.ToString();
            int newNumber;
            if (int.TryParse(stVal ,out newNumber))
            {                
                BindNumber = newNumber;
                vNA = false;
            }else{             
                BindNumber = null;
            }
            
        }
    }
    protected async Task OnCheckedChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string stVal = e.Value.ToString();
            Boolean newChecked;
            if (Boolean.TryParse(stVal ,out newChecked))
            {
                if (newChecked)
                {
                    BindNumber = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you should use the validation that comes with Blazor out of the box, rather than trying to roll your own.  You can read more about how Blazor validation works [here](https://blazor-university.com/forms/validation/).

Comment: That would be fine for the red range validation but for the amber ranges (outliers that are allowed but need confirming) there is a UI behavior directly associated with the validation. So using the out of the box validation would mean adding a datapoint for the confirm box, writing (more standard) custom validation that used both that and the numeric value and having to update the ranges in both the UI (for hide/show of confirm) and the data annotation(for the validation).

Comment: Net6 or 7?  It makes a difference in how the binds are implemented.  Also are you open to a suggestion on how to approach this a little differently?

Comment: 6 but planning on upgrading to 8 so 7 is probably better. And yes open to suggestion. I guess I'm just trying to replicate behavior from a web forms project that had a lot of controls with custom validators that asked for confirmation when things were slightly unusual. But there may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a seriously refactored version of your control.

It:

- uses a select to only show "valid" values and adds the confirm button if the value is in the warning range.
- uses bootstrap for Css - you might be using somehing different.
- interacts with the `EditContext` and updates the validation store.

**LimitedNumberInput**

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<div class="input-group mb-3">

    @*the ValueChanged is convoluted to get around an SDK issue that seems to keep coming and going in updates*@

    <InputSelect class="form-select"
                 Value="this.Value" 
        ValueChanged="(int? value) => this.OnValueChanged(value)" 
        ValueExpression="this.ValueExpression" >
    
        @*Uses int.MinValue as a token to represent a null value*@
        @if (this.Value is null)
        {
            <option value="@int.MinValue" selected>@this.NotSelectedText</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@int.MinValue">@this.NotSelectedText</option>
        }

        @for (int counter = this.Min; counter <= this.Max; counter++)
        {
            var value = counter;
            <option class="@GetOptionCss(value)" value="@value">@value</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>

    @if (_mustConfirm)
    {
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button disabled="@_confirmed" class="@_btnCss" @onclick="this.OnConfirm">@_btnText</button>
        </div>
    }

</div>

<ValidationMessage For="this.ValueExpression" />

@code {
    private ValidationMessageStore? _store;
    private bool _confirmed;

    private bool _mustConfirm => this.Value < MinWarning || this.Value > MaxWarning;
    private string _btnText => _confirmed ? "Confirmed" : "Confirm";
    private string _btnCss => _confirmed ? "btn btn-success" : "btn btn-danger";

    [Parameter] public int Max { get; set; } = 50;
    [Parameter] public int Min { get; set; } = -10;
    [Parameter] public int MaxWarning { get; set; } = 40;
    [Parameter] public int MinWarning { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public string NotSelectedText { get; set; } = "Not Applicable";

    [Parameter] public int? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<int?>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? _editContext { get; set; }

    // formats the values in the warning zone with the warning colour 
    private string GetOptionCss(int value)
        => value < MinWarning || value > MaxWarning
            ? "text-warning"
            : string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Get our validation store if we have an edit context
        if (_editContext is not null)
            _store = new(_editContext);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _store?.Clear();

        var isValidationError = _mustConfirm && !_confirmed;

        // Check to see if we need to add the validation message
        if (isValidationError && this.ValueExpression is not null)
            {
                var fi = FieldIdentifier.Create(this.ValueExpression);
                _store?.Add(fi, "You must confirm the unusual value you have selected");

            }
    }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(int? value)
    {
        // always reset the confirmed flag if we have changed the value
        _confirmed = false;

        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value == int.MinValue ? null : value);
    }

    private void OnConfirm()
        => _confirmed = true;
}
```

And the demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<EditForm Model="_model">

    <LimitedNumberInput @bind-Value="_model.StartValue" />
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value : @_model.StartValue</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Model _model = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public int? StartValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I took you at your word.  This does demonstrate how to interact with the edit context and validation store.  If the range is too great you can also use a number control and then not let the user enter numbers above or below the limits.

Answer (score 0):

I was mostly trying to avoid having to maintain the same ranges in different places and risk them becoming out of sync but I came up with a plan. Rather than keep on battling with trying to put validation in the components, I defined the parameters elsewhere so both the component and validation could use them.

So I made a kind of settings file for the ranges and  added a property for the confirm checked in the view model It defaults to true and is changed to false in the component if the numeric value is changed to something out of range out of range. The true default makes validation more efficient (no need to load parameters or check amber ranage if its confirmed) and allows for re-save of existing values without having to confirm again.

So the settings

```
public class NumericRanges
{
    public string Datafield;
    public int? RedMin;
    public int? RedMax;
    public int? AmberMin;
    public int? AmberMax;

    public NumericRanges(string _Datafield,int? _RedMin,int?_RedMax, int? _AmberMin, int? _AmberMax)
    {
        Datafield = _Datafield;
        RedMin = _RedMin;
        RedMax = _RedMax;
        AmberMin = _AmberMin;
        AmberMax = _AmberMax;
}

}
public class RangesFor_Location
{
    public List<NumericRanges> FormNumericRanges;

    public RangesFor_Location()
    {
        FormNumericRanges = new List<NumericRanges>();
        FormNumericRanges.Add(new NumericRanges("ChartDayStartMinute", 0, 60, 14, 46));
        FormNumericRanges.Add(new NumericRanges("ChartDayStartHour", 0, 24, 0, 12));
    }
}
```

there will be a RangesFor_  class for each form

Then both the form and validation code have

> ```
>  public RangesFor_Location RangesForForm;
>     public  NumericRanges RangeForField(string dataField)
>     {
>         if (RangesForForm == null){ RangesForForm = new RangesFor_Location(); }
>
>         NumericRanges NR = RangesForForm.FormNumericRanges
>                             .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Datafield == dataField);
>         return NR;
>     }
> ```

On the form

```
 <NumberWithNAAndAmberRanges2
 @bind-BindNumber="LocVM.ChartDayStartMinute" 
     @bind-AmberRange_ConfrimChk="LocVM.ChartDayStartMinute_Confirmed"
     NaName="Not Applicable"  NaAllowed="true" NumericRangesForm="@RangeForField("ChartDayStartMinute")" />  />
     <ValidationMessage For="() => LocVM.ChartDayStartMinute" />
```

Then in the fluent validation code

```
   RuleFor(x => x.ChartDayStartMinute).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
                .NotEmpty()
                .Must((ChartDayStartMinute) => Be_WithinRedRangeNumberic(ChartDayStartMinute, "ChartDayStartMinute")).WithMessage("Outside of red ranges")
                .Must((fooArgs, ChartDayStartMinute) => Be_WithinAmberRangeNumberic(fooArgs.ChartDayStartMinute_Confirmed, ChartDayStartMinute, "ChartDayStartMinute")).WithMessage("Please confirm unusual value");


        }
        private bool Be_WithinAmberRangeNumberic(Boolean? conf, int? ValueIn, string dataField)
        {
            if (conf == null) { conf = false; }
            if (!(ValueIn == null || ValueIn == -1 || conf == true))             
            {

            NumericRanges NR = RangeForField(dataField);
                    if (NR.AmberMin != null)
                    {
                        if (NR.AmberMin > ValueIn)
                        { return false; }
                    }
                    if (NR.AmberMax != null)
                    {
                        if (NR.AmberMax < ValueIn)
                        { return false; }
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
        private bool Be_WithinRedRangeNumberic( int? ValueIn, string dataField)
        {    
            if (!(ValueIn == null || ValueIn == -1))
            {
            NumericRanges NR = RangeForField(dataField);
                if (NR.RedMin != null)
                {
                    if (NR.RedMin > ValueIn)
                    { return false; }
                }
                if (NR.RedMax != null)
                {
                    if (NR.RedMax < ValueIn)
                    { return false; }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```